# Model isn’t updating when I use a query

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The model automatically updates if I use:

```
ST.FiltersSymbolsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
  return this.store.find('filter');
  }
});
```

But when I introduce a query, the model does not automatically update:

```
ST.FiltersSymbolsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
  return this.store.find('filter', {isSymbol: true});
  }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsbin.com/yeyiroyo/1/2

To replicate the bug, click Symbols, click "+", type something, and hit enter You'll notice that nothing happens, but if you click Users, then Symbols again -- you'll notice that the model has updated. How can we make it update immediately?

I think what I need to do is have a hook that refreshes the model here:

```
filter.save().then(function(){
  //reload the model
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is going to return a record array not a individual record.

```
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('filter', {isSymbol: true}).then( 
      function(results) {
        return results.get('firstObject')
      }
    );
  }
```

If you want to return the record array and have it populate automatically then do:

```
model: function() {
   return this.store.filter('filter', {isSymbol: true}, function(record) {
      return record.get('isSymbol') === true;
   });
}
```

Here is a good write up.

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/

Comment: tried adding this in-- got the error: 
    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'

Comment: That sounds like you are adding a object to an array controller.

Comment: love you! -- removed the object as a parameter for the first return statement of the second example you gave and worked perfectly